# Can not register a Scala UDF for pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark, I want to use a Scala UDF to filter an array with arbitrary member type.

```
package com.example.spark.udf

import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2


class ArrayFilterGt[T] extends UDF2[WrappedArray[T], T, WrappedArray[T]] {

  override def call(x: WrappedArray[T], y: T): WrappedArray[T] = (x, y) match {
    case (null, _) => null
    case (_, null) => x
    case (x, y) => x.filter(_ > y )
  }
}
```

But build error.

```
[info] Loading settings from plugin.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /some_path/spark-scala-util/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to spark-scala-util (in build file:/some_path/spark-scala-util/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2018/04/19 8:32:32
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /some_path/spark-scala-util/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /some_path/spark-scala-util/src/main/scala/ArrayFilterGt.scala:13:31: value > is not a member of type parameter T
[error]     case (x, y) => x.filter(_ > y )
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed 2018/04/19 8:32:39
```

It would be quite basic mistake.
But, since I am not familiar with Scala/Java, I cannot resolve it. Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**

I tried `[T <% Ordered[T]]` and built it.

```
class ArrayFilterGt[T <% Ordered[T]] extends UDF2[WrappedArray[T], T, WrappedArray[T]] {

  override def call(x: WrappedArray[T], y: T): WrappedArray[T] = (x, y) match {
    case (null, _) => null
    case (_, null) => x
    case (x, y) => x.filter(_ > y )
  }
}
```

But I could not register it on Pyspark.

```
spark_session.udf.registerJavaFunction(
    name='date_array_gt',
    javaClassName='com.example.spark.udf.ArrayFilterGt',
    returnType=ArrayType(elementType=DateType(), containsNull=True),
)
```

error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Can not instantiate class com.example.spark.udf.ArrayFilterGt, please make sure it has public non argument constructor;'
```

Also, `com.example.spark.udf.ArrayFilterGt[Date]` raises same error.

Since the other scala UDFs can be successfully registered and used, `--jars` option is not problem.

Comment: Can't you write the udf in pyspark ?

Comment: Since my dateframe has 2 billion rows and python UDF takes time, I want to use scala UDF.